# SQL Server Performance Tuning of large table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of 755 columns and around holding 2 million records as of now and it will grow.There are many procedures accessing it with other tables join, are running slow.  Now it's hard to split/normalize them as everything is already built and customer is not ready to spend much on it. Is there any way to make the query access to that table faster? Please advise.

Will column store index help?

Comment: *755 columns* - a lot has gone wrong there already. Indexes will help but as your question is too broad we can help you no more than giving you this hint.

Comment: 755 columns? That's must be a record on StackOverflow for sure. I will say to you, not in a bad way, tell your costumer URGENTLY to stop and build everything from scratch. 755 columns? Ooooh boy!! It hurts just to read it.

Comment: If the query must scan a lot of data and a subset of columns are needed, columnstore will probably help.

Comment: Probably, for now, you can move historical data to a history table? and alter the logic to accommodate situation?

Comment: 755 columns is a killer for row-chaining. In my mind there is no good way of solution except reducing number of columns. You may try to divide into multiple tables and play with indexes.

Comment: How little are the prepared to spend? It may be possible to split this table into multiple 1 to 1 joined tables (vertical partitioning), then use a view to present it as one single blob to existing code. With some luck you may get join elimination happening. See: http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/09/15/vertical-partitioning-as-the-way-to-reduce-io/ and https://logicalread.com/sql-server-optimizer-may-eliminate-foreign-key-joins-mc11/#.WXgEzlERW6I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How little are they prepared to spend?

It may be possible to split this table into multiple 1 to 1 joined tables (vertical partitioning), then use a view to present it as one single blob to existing code.

With some luck you may get join elimination happening frequently enough to make it worthwhile.

View will probably require `INSTEAD OF` triggers to fully replicate existing logic. `INSTEAD OF` triggers have a number of restrictions e.g. no support for `OUTPUT` clause, which can prove to be to hard to overcome depending on your specific setup.

You can name your view the same as existing table, which will eliminate the need of fixing code everywhere.

IMO this is the simplest you can do short of a full DB re-factoring exercise.

See: http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/09/15/vertical-partitioning-as-the-way-to-reduce-io/ and https://logicalread.com/sql-server-optimizer-may-eliminate-foreign-key-joins-mc11/#.WXgEzlERW6I

Answer (score 0):

755 Columns thats a lot. You should try to index the columns that are mostly used in where clause. this might speed up the process

Answer (score 0):

It is fine, dont worry about it, actually how many columns you have it is not important in sql server (But be careful I said 'have'). The main problem is data count and how many column you select in queries. There is a few point firstly you can check.

1. Do not use * selector and change it if used in everywhere
2. In the joins, do not use it directly, you can firstly filter it as inner select. (Just try it, I have no idea about your table so I m telling the general rules.)
3. Try the diminish data count for ex: use history table for old records. This technicque depends on needs of your organization.
4. Try to use column index and something like that features.
5. And of course remove dynamic selects in your queries.

I wish one of them will work.